# How to restore a deleted package in android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, restore, recover

Unfortunately I deleted my **res** folder of my android project. I am using intellij IDEA IDE. 
I didn't had any backup of my project, can anybody help me restoring the res folder. I don't want to make the whole app again.

Comment: Get your last apk you built. Extract it as regular ZIP archive. You will get your res folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Restoring the package from the Local History`

Steps are located here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/restoring-a-file-from-local-history.html

Best of luck!